# the response of wireless channel to an input

Tags: wireless, communication, output

I am reading the wireless of David Tse. In the 2nd chapter of this book there is a discussion about the response of the channel due to an input. It has said that since the channel is linear its output can be written as

\$ y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h(\tau,t)x(t-\tau)d\tau\$

which \$h(\tau,t)\$ is the response at time \$t\$ to an impulse transmitted at time \$t-\tau\$ and can be obtained through the following formula:

\$h(\tau,t)=\sum_{i}a_{i}(t)\delta(\tau-\tau_{i}(t))\$

in which \$a_{i}(t)\$ is the amplification or attenuation due to different propagation pathes and \$\tau_{i}(t)\$ is its relevant delay. Now I have several questions that I will be thankful if someone helps me.

1- Does "an impulse transmitted at time \$t-\tau\$" means \$\delta(t-\tau)\$? (since in this case the author must wrote "an impulse transmitted at time \$\tau\$")

2- Due to this fact that we know the output concerned with an input can be obtained through the formula \$y(t)=\sum_{i}a_{i}(t)x(t-\tau_{i}(t))\$, how does formula of \$h(\tau,t)\$ have been derived?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response of any LTI system to an input can be computed, in the time domain, by convolution of the input signal and the system's transfer function. It also happens that the transfer function equals the system's impulse response. So by using a convolution with the impulse response of the system and the applied input, the response of the system to that input can be computed. The first equation you have there is the convolution equation.

Things are much easier to compute if everything is mapped to the s domain by using a Laplace transform. In the s domain, convolution becomes a simple multiplication.

You can find more details on the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTI_system_theory) article for LTI systems and in many textbooks.

```
1- Does "an impulse transmitted at time t−τ" means δ(t−τ)?
```

The phrase "which \$h(\tau,t)\$ is the response at time t to an impulse transmitted at time \$t−\tau\$" is a not so great way of saying "the impulse response of the system" so you are correct. Note that since the system is considered time invariant, the time the impulse is transmitted doesn't matter.

```
2- how does formula of h(τ,t) have been derived?
```

This is the system transfer function in the time domain. It can be derived by combining the dynamic equations that describe how the system evolves over time. It can also be derived experimentally by using system identification techniques. The simplest method being to excite the system using an impulse and just record the response. This is not always desirable. More info can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is worded correctly but might be confusing. The response is a function of time t which includes the response of the impulse which does occur at time \$t=\tau\$

More commonly these are referenced at the same time, but he is just talking general terms.  Typically values prior to \$t=\tau\$ of h are ignored because in a linear/causal system they should be zero when evaluating a channel's impulse response.

The impulse response can be derived mathematically or via measurement.

Typically in EE applications the system's impulse can be found taking the inverse laplace of the transfer function.  This is a convenient notation to work with because the laplace transform of the impulse function is 1 and time convolution is simply multiplication in laplace space.  Here are some examples from physics.  http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Transient/TransInputs/TransImpulse.html